# Member function of abstract class which is a derived class of another abstract class

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I want to define the member function `area()` and `volume()` separately in two abstract classes `Shapes_2D` and `Shapes_3D`, which are derive class of another abstract base class `Shapes`. But I got the error:

```
no member named 'area' in 'Shapes'
```

Here's my code:

```cpp
class Shapes
{
protected:
    unsigned int dim;       
public:
    virtual ~Shapes() {}
    Shapes(unsigned int x) : dim{x} {}
    unsigned int getDim() { return dim; }
};

class Shapes_2D : public Shapes
{
public:
    Shapes_2D() : Shapes{2} {}
    virtual double area() = 0;  
};

class Shapes_3D : public Shapes
{
public:
    Shapes_3D() : Shapes{3} {}
    virtual double volume() = 0;
};

class Rectangle : public Shapes_2D
{
private:
    double width;
    double height;
public:
    Rectangle(double w, double h) : width{w}, height{h} {}
    double area() {return width * height;};
};
```

Here's how I tried to use `area()`

```cpp
Shapes *rectangle = new Rectangle(2, 3);
rectangle->area();
```

I can fix this by defining `volume()` in the 2D base class:

```cpp
class Shapes
{
public:
    // ...
    virtual double area() = 0;
    virtual double volume() = 0;
};
class Shapes_2D : public Shapes
{
public:
    // ...
    double area() { return 0; }  
    double volume() { return 0; }
};
```

Is there a way to avoid define the `volume()` in the 2D class since it doesn't make sense.

Comment: If it makes sense for a `Shapes` to have a volume, and it makes sense for a `Shapes_2D`  to be a `Shapes`, it must make sense for a `Shapes_2D` to have a volume. Whether it is a problem for a 2D shape to have volume zero rather than no volume depends on what you're trying to express.

Comment: Volume in 2D is the area. If you are working with multiple dimensions, I would suggest you use that term, and include the vrtual function `volume` in the base class `Shape`.

Comment: Side note: don't use a plural name, like "Shapes", for a type that represents a single thing, like a shape. You're only going to confuse yourself.

Comment: Another side note: three-dimensional objects have surface areas.

Comment: 3D shapes typically have a surface area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intent to calculate the area of `rectangle`, then the type of `rectangle` must be `Shapes_2D*` or `D*` where `D` is derived from `Shapes_2D`. If you declare `rectangle` with type `Shapes*`, then how do you know it actually is a 2D shape that has an area? It could be pointing to something that is a 3D shape and doesn't have an area.

So:

```
Shapes_2D *rectangle = new Rectangle(2, 3);
```

(Also, from a mathematical viewpoint, there are several possibilities to interpret "area" and "volume", so that maybe your separation into distinct properties for 2D and 3D doesn't really make sense.)

Answer (score 0):

This would not be possible, as the type of `rectangle` has to be `Shapes_2D` or `Rectangle` The compiler will not know that `rectangle` is a `Rectangle`!

If you do not want to hardcode the type of the variable in the code (e.g. you have an array of shapes of different types) you need to add `area` and `volume` to the `Shapes` class, in order to be able to acces it on a `Shapes` pointer!

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious to you that a rectangle has an area, therefore it feels like this should work:

```
Shapes *rectangle = new Rectangle(2, 3);
rectangle->area();
```

But those are just names you've given to things, and the compiler does not know your domain.

See it from the compiler's perspective:

```
Base * baseptr = make_object_that_is_or_inherits_from_Base(arguments);
baseptr->function_that_is_not_in_Base();
```

Or, adding back some domain knowledge but showing explicitly why it doesn't - and *shouldn't* - work:

```
Shape2D * shape2D = get_any_shape_at_random() //might return 1D shape "line";
shape->area();
```

The fundamental disconnect is that by using a `Shape*` for this, you are explicitly telling the compiler to forget that this is a 2D shape. This is any arbitrary object that inherits from Shape. For all the compiler knows, this could be a cat, if you did `class Cat : public Shape`.

If you want the compiler to know that this is a pointer to a 2D shape, you should let the compiler know that:

```
Shape2D * shape2D = new Rectangle(dim1, dim2);
shape2D->area();
```